# Problem with setting Farm Account

Tags: database, configuration, server-farm, configuration-wizard

I am currently trying to setup a farm for my fresh sharepoint installation (before i run the configuration wizard) and set a local account for the farm admin. I ran this cmd using sharepoint Management Shell,

```
New-SPConfigurationDatabse
-DatabaseName; FarmDatabase_2
-DatabaseServer; Sharepoint2010dev (computer's name)
-FarmCredentials; Administrator:pw
-Passphrase; !baba12345
```

[image: http://imgur.com/emNPa]

And i get this error, does anyone know what's the problem ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close and reopen the shell fixed it...